# How do registrars register authoritative name servers with root name servers?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registrar

I understand that domain name registrars, for each domain they manage, register the authoritative name servers for that domain with its top-level root name server.

My question is: how do they do this? Is there a special protocol they use? How do top-level root name servers authenticate queries from registrars to change authoritative name servers for a given domain? Is that even public knowledge?

For example, say you own example.com. You want to change the authoritative name servers for it. You give your registrar the addresses of the new name servers. So far, so good. They, in turn, echo that change with the top-level root name server (the one responsible for .com). What protocol is used for the query from your registrar? How does that root name server authenticate it? How does it know it's legit?

*Migrated from SuperUser ([https://superuser.com/questions/910123/how-do-registrars-register-authoritative-name-servers-with-root-name-servers)](https://superuser.com/questions/910123/how-do-registrars-register-authoritative-name-servers-with-root-name-servers)_)*

Comment: @MichaelHampton What's wrong with wanting to know how something works? I never said I wanted to do that myself. I'm curious. Is all.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Many registries use the Extensible Provisioning Protocol (EPP)](https://www6.ietf.org/iesg/implementation/report-rfc4930-4934.txt) to facilitate their registrar interactions.
It's worth noting that this is a whole separate protocol from DNS itself, specifically dealing with name registration and provisioning. It only indirectly populates the relevant zone in DNS.

Unless you are either a registry or a registrar it really doesn't matter much what sort of protocols / APIs these parties use but if you do want to read up on it, here are some of the relevant specs for EPP:

- [Extensible Provisioning Protocol
  (EPP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5730)
- [Extensible Provisioning
  Protocol (EPP) Domain Name
  Mapping](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5731)
- [Extensible
  Provisioning Protocol (EPP) Host
  Mapping](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5732)
- [Extensible
  Provisioning Protocol (EPP) Contact
  Mapping](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5733)
- [Extensible
  Provisioning Protocol (EPP) Transport over
  TCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5734)
- [Domain Name System (DNS)
  Security Extensions Mapping for the Extensible Provisioning Protocol
  (EPP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5910)

As more of a sidenote, the root servers deal with the root zone (aka `.`), a TLD zone is not the same as the "root". If you register for instance `example.com` through your registrar nothing changes in the root zone, your delegation is only entered into the `com` zone.

Comment: Thanks for making the distinction between the root zone and the gTLD zones in your answer. A lot of people incorrectly conflate the two.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this became an issue in our environment when the registrar failed to update the IP for our name-servers and hence some providers were still querying the old IP and causing intermittent errors on our network. Very tricky to track down but also good to know how it works and that moving your DNS to another provider isn't the complete scenario. Updating the registrar with the new IP is critical.

Comment: "hence some providers were still querying the old IP" This would happen only if you use glues. That is one of their shortcomings, you need to remember to update their IP and hence their specific registration at the registry, which needs to go through the registrar. Otherwise, just using nameservers (names) nothing happens at registry or registrar regarding IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so let's start from the beginning. When you buy a domain name, it's recorded with a **domain registrar** or **domain name registrar**

*NB: 1) A **domain name registrar** is a **company** that manages the reservation of Internet domain names. They're basically in charge of managing and safekeeping your domain name for future use. Examples of domain name registrars are ****GoDaddy, Namecheap,** etc**.*

*Before registering a domain name, we pick an appropriate **TLD Top-Level Domain** for the website which is the **last part** of a domain name after the last **dot**, such as **‘.com’**, **‘.org’**, **‘.net’**, and so on. Great!*

***ICANN (Internet Corporation of Assigned Names and Numbers)** manages the two types of TLDs - **generic Top Level Domains (gTLDs) [.com, .net, .org, etc.]** and **country-code Top Level Domains ccTLDs. [.ca, .de, .ng, etc.]***

*All domain registrars operate according to the guidelines provided by **ICANN**. Great!*

So if you buy (i.e. register) the domain name https://www.example.com/ and host the website on any of the famous domain registrars such as GoDaddy or Namecheap - let's take GoDaddy as an example - by default, GoDaddy will provide an **A record** on an **authoritative nameserver**, which connects

1. the *IP address* of *exmaple.com website's server* to
2. the *domain name* (https://www.example.com/)

they broadcast this "A Record" generated by the domain registrar to the respective TLD name server (.com).

*NB:
2) A **resolver** (or DNS resolver) is a DNS server that runs a **recursive process** to retrieve the IP address of a domain name.*

*It's the first DNS server to get the ball rolling in the sense that it makes the first request to a **root nameserver**, which points it to the respective **TLD nameserver** which in turn points it to the **authoritative nameserver.**
The **authoritative nameserver** returns the IP address it's looking for. It's the resolver that also responds to the user by handing over the required IP address to the host (the browser). The resolver's full-time job is to retrieve the IP address of a domain name (https://www.example.com) from the **authoritative nameserver.***

*The **resolver**, the **root nameserver**, the **TLD nameserver**, and the **authoritative nameserver** are the **4 DNS nameservers** that perform **DNS resolution.** The resolver performs a recursive process (requesting from each server), while the others perform an iterative process (the search through their lists of IP addresses and domain names). Great!*

Now, the resolver (a DNS server Infrastructure provided by your ISP) receives the IP address as a response and returns the IP address to the browser to initiate a TCP/IP handshake. Great!
But that's if you host on the Domain Registrars themselves. What if you want to host on Netlify or Vercel?

So, you've registered the domain with GoDaddy, right? You now have an A record **192.0.56.210 https://www.example.com** let's say.
It contains the attachment of the IP address of the example.com website's server 192.0.56.210, with the Domain name (https://www.example.com/).

All you need to do is visit Vercel and update the IP address of the web application with **192.0.56.210**.

Now, the IP address on GoDaddy will be pointing to the website server - which is your Vercel server.