# Are NS records for a .com domain stored by the registrar or the .com registry?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone, domain-registrar, domain-registration

Let's say I own `example.com`, that I bought by `ExampleRegistrar`.
Let's say that, by default, this registrar uses their own nameservers `ns1.exampleregistrar.com`, `ns2.exampleregistrar.com`.

Thus, when a client wants to browse to `www.example.com`, it probably goes like this:

- root DNS servers looks for `.com` nameserver
- `.com` nameserver looks for `example.com`, it sees `ns1.exampleregistrar.com` and passes the request to this nameserver
- `ns1.exampleregistrar.com` looks for `www.example.com` and finally finds IP `203.0.113.5` which it gives to the client.

**Question: how does it work if I configure a custom nameserver `ns1.othernameserver.com` in the registrar domain's settings?**

Does this mean the registry for `.com` will *directly* have `ns1.othernameserver.com` in its database?

Is it correct that, then, any request from a client to `www.example.com` will *never* go through any of the registrar's servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registrar essentially just deals with sales and customer interactions, they are not part of the actual live operations from a DNS perspective.
Well, not as part of their role as a registrar, anyway. It's very common that registrar companies also provide DNS hosting services for customer zones, but that is just a case of value-add or upsell of non-registrar services to their customers.

From a registry as well as DNS operational perspective there is no difference functionally if you used registrar-provided nameservers, third party nameservers, your own nameservers, or any mix of these.

In all these cases, the registrar just sends the set of `NS` records that the registrant has selected (maybe implicitly if you choose to use their DNS hosting services) to the registry and those are published in the TLD zone.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure to understand, let's take `stackoverflow.com` as an example. It seems that their first nameserver is `NS-1033.AWSDNS-01.ORG`.  Is this a correct way to see the path: first using one of the 13 root servers: `dig @198.41.0.4 stackoverflow.com` => this gives us nameservers for `com.` (registry?), for example `a.gtld-servers.net.` i.e. `192.5.6.30`. Then we can do `dig @192.5.6.30 stackoverflow.com` and then we see the 4 nameservers, including `ns-1033.awsdns-01.org.`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Basj Yes, something like `dig @a.root-servers.net stackoverflow.com`, `dig @a.gtld-servers.net stackoverflow.com`, `dig @ns-1033.awsdns-01.org stackoverflow.com` would be a valid example of manually reproducing the lookup steps.

Comment: Last thing @HåkanLindqvist: how does the registrar "send" the information *"Dear TLD .com registry, please now use `ns.anothernameserver.com` as nameserver for the domain `example.com` - we are the official registar for `example.com`, proof: XYZ."*, what's the name of this process / automated API, out of curiosity? I'd like to understand how a registrar proves to the registry that they are authorized to do this, and how they ask to update the registry database.

Comment: @Basj It varies, but often EPP. See https://serverfault.com/questions/688837/how-do-registrars-register-authoritative-name-servers-with-root-name-servers/689852#689852